# How Can I Format Money in a DataGrid with $?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to format monetary values in my `DataGrid` so that they start with the dollar sign (`$`).

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I understand this question.  She's trying to format the cells in a particular column to have a numeric format.  @Nikki196 - if that's right, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn.itemstyle.aspx  Although I do have to say, it helps to add a bit more detail to your questions and list what you've already tried.  Check the FAQ as shown in the "Closed as not a real question" block.

Comment: I agree with @DavidStratton. This isn't a great question, and it's poorly-worded. But it is answerable. I'd want to know if this is WinForms, ASP .NET, or WPF though.

Comment: @Nikki196 - I took a look at your other question, and I think it would be very helpful for you to review John Skeet's blog post on writing the perfect question. It makes it a LOT easier for us to help if we have enough information to answer it.  http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @Yuck Thank you so much for your comments and editing.. Yeah I am working on winforms

Comment: @DavidStratton Thanks, I am going to look on this post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about showing the data in a monetary format, or even simply adding a "$" to the beginning of data so that

1.49

displays as

$1.49

then you can do this in several ways.  On a DataGrid control (web) you can set the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn.dataformatstring.aspx) property.

One option is to set it to "c" for Currency on a BoundColumn.  This will work if your web server's [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) is set to en-US

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="CurrencyValue" 
                 HeaderText="Price"
                 DataFormatString="{0:c}">
```

Another option is to use a CustomFormatString, which gives you more refined control over how it's displayed.  Say you always want it to be EXACTLY three digits to the right of the decimal and EXACTLY two digits to the left, you can use

{0:$00.000}

More information on custom data format strings for numbers can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Since you're working in WinForms, (sorry, I just re-read the comments) you would use the same technique but apply it to the column's DefaultCellStyle as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx

```
dataGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

Answer (score 2):

Also if you are looking for a Culture-specific cell formatting with a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you can use the FormatProvider Property of [DataGridCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In WinForms:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["MoneyValue"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
dataGridView1.Columns["MoneyValue"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CO");
```